# Read/Write from textfile using openFileOutput

Tags: android, android-file

I'm making an app and it will use a text file to store a password. I'm currently trying to save this password to the file, it looks like it saves but I cannot know because I cannot read from the file.

Straight after I attempt to save the password to the file, I attempt to show the contents of the file in the same textfield they used to enter the string (this is just to test if it saved) but nothing comes up.

```
    public class setPin extends ActionBarActivity {


private final static String STORETEXT = "storetext.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_pin);

}

public void buttonClick(View v) {
    EditText txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(STORETEXT,         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        out.write(txtEditor.getText().toString());
        txtEditor.setText("");
        fos.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(),    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

 //HERE I TRY TO PRINT THE SAVED STRING INTO THE TEXTFIELD

    try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(STORETEXT)));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
        }
        txtEditor.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
    EditText txtEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(STORETEXT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(txtEditor.getText().toString().getBytes());
        txtEditor.setText("");
        fos.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    String contents = "";
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(STORETEXT);
        int i;
        while ((i = fin.read()) != -1) {
            contents = contents + Character.toString((char) i);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    txtEditor.setText(contents);
}
```

Comment: The line fos.write(txtEditor.getText().toString());     

cannot resolve method 'write(java.lang.String).

Comment: It shows up in the text field now so it looks like it's working, thanks so much